# Executing an update stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to know, if I am writing the stored procedure correctly and If the C# code for executing is correct. for some reason the error being returned as is Incorrect syntax near 'c16b'. Old Error

The new error now is: Procedure or function 'sptimeupdate' expects parameter '@date', which was not supplied.

the nvarchar string for validating and updating in the column by ClientID is 3fc8ffa1-**c16b**-4d7b-9e55-1e88dfe15277, but the part in bold is only showing in the debug test intel sense in error handling

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sptimeupdate
    @id nvarchar(50),
    @date datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE ClientTable
    SET Today_Date=(@date)
    WHERE ClientID=(@id)
END

//--------------above stored procedure--------------------------------
//--------------Executing the stored procedure in C#

 IEnumerable<XElement> searchClientID =
 from clientid in main.XPathSelectElements("Network/ClientID")
 where (string)clientid.Attribute("id") == IntializedPorts[i].ToString()
 select clientid;

foreach (string clientid in searchClientID)
  {
     for (int up = 0; up < IntializedPorts.Count(); up++)
     {
          //Update the current time in the clientid tble.
          //Renames the table copy for groups
      try
       {
         string[] Clientid; //client id array
         Clientid = new string[IntializedPorts.Count()]; //Intialization of the array
         Clientid[up] = clientid.ToString();
         DateTime td = Convert.ToDateTime(toolDate.Text); //Just added a datetime object withdate
 SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString = new SqlConnection(@"Data=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Shawn\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Server\database\ClientRegit.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

   //EXECUTE THE STORED PROCEDURE sptimedate
   // string UpdateCommand = "sptimeupdate" + Clientid[up].ToString() + toolDate.Text;
   string UpdateCommand = "sptimeupdate" + "'" + Clientid[up].ToString() + "'" + "'" +td.ToString()+ "'"; //this is the new UpdateCommand string as to pass parameters to stored procedure 
    SqlCommand sqlRenameCommand = new SqlCommand(UpdateCommand, sqlConnectionCmdString);

    sqlConnectionCmdString.Open();
    sqlRenameCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnectionCmdString.Close();
  }
  catch(DataException ex)
  {                                                                                                 MessageBox.Show("Failed to UpdateCurrentTime","DataError",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }

 }

}
```

Comment: If you could also please could you show in code for coverting the SQL data connection string to a global string so that it can be found on any computer instead of just mine? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I changed the code some and now its giving me a different Error , its saying its not giving the datetime to the datetime parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a stored procedure from code you need to create a command with its command type set to StoredProcedure, otherwise the engine tries to use your command text as it was an sql text like SELECT INSERT etc... But the mose important thing is that you need to pass the parameters required by the stored procedure in the Parameters collection of the command

So this could be the code to replace the actual one

```
string UpdateCommand = "sptimeupdate";
using(SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString = new SqlConnection(......))
using(SqlCommand sqlRenameCommand = new SqlCommand(UpdateCommand, sqlConnectionCmdString))
{
    DateTime td = Convert.ToDateTime(toolDate.Text);
    sqlRenameCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
    sqlRenameCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Clientid[up].ToString();
    sqlRenameCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = td;
    sqlConnectionCmdString.Open();
    sqlRenameCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Notice two things. The using statement is the best practice to follow when you create a connection to ensure the correct closing and disposing of the connection, second, the parameter for the DateTime expected by the sp should be passed as a DateTime not as a string- Of course this means that you should be certain that the content of toolDate is convertible to a DateTime value.

Comment: I tried exactly the way you have it, and I get the same result both yours and my way will both work - but I still get an error that says Procedure or function 'sptimeupdate' expects parameter '@date', which was not supplied.

Comment: Sorry my bad, the parameter name is date, fixing it now

Comment: However consider also the approach outlined by Bernd Linde in its answer. If the number of loops is small there is no big difference, but with many items keeping the construction of the parameter collection outside the loop and just setting the values inside the loop is preferable

Answer (score 1):

Your error is originating from this line of code:

```
string UpdateCommand = "sptimeupdate" + Clientid[up].ToString() + toolDate.Text;
```

There you are just concatenating the `Clientid[up].ToString()` as a string into the other string, same with the `toolDate.Text`, both without and sql markup.
Your resulting SQL query would look like this (assuming toolDate.Text is '2014-10-23'):

```
sptimeupdate3fc8ffa1-c16b-4d7b-9e55-1e88dfe152772014-10-23
```

which as you can see is not a proper SQL command.

You should **always** use parametrized command statements when calling simple SQL commands.
**However** in your case, you are actually calling a stored procedure.

So change your code to handle it like a stored procedure, example below.

```
// Create the connection object once
using (SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString = new SqlConnection(@"Data=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Shawn\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Server\database\ClientRegit.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
{
  // Same with the SqlCommand object and adding the parameters once also
  SqlCommand sqlRenameCommand = new SqlCommand("sptimeupdate", sqlConnectionCmdString);
  sqlRenameCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  sqlRenameCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
  sqlRenameCommand.Parameters.Add("@datetime", SqlDbType.DateTime);

  // Open the connection once only
  sqlConnectionCmdString.Open();

  foreach (string clientid in searchClientID)
  {
    for (int up = 0; up < IntializedPorts.Count; up++)
    {
      try
      {
        // The below three lines seem redundant.
        // Clientid[up] will be equal to clientid after it all, so just use clientid
        //string[] Clientid;
        //Clientid = new string[IntializedPorts.Count];
        //Clientid[up] = clientid.ToString();

        sqlRenameCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = clientid;
        sqlRenameCommand.Parameters["@datetime"].Value = toolDate.Text;
        sqlRenameCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      // Might want to move this try..catch outside the two loops,
      // otherwise you will get this message each time an error happens
      // which might be alot, depending on the side of searchClientID
      catch (SqlException)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to UpdateCurrentTime", "DataError", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:**
Please read the comments inside the code above for additional advice and suggestions.
Recreating a SqlConnection and SqlCommand for each iteration will have a performance impact on your application. So rather create them once and reuse them until you are done.

Further reading can be done here:

- [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (There are nice examples at the bottom of that page)
- [dotnetperls version of SqlCommand](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand)

P.S. your sql procedure's code looks fine, you could remove the `SET NOTCOUNT ON` since that does not really do much in this scenario

Comment: Thanks, Look I changed the UpdateCommand string, and it now is looking for only the Datetime parameter

Comment: The problem is the way the string was being built to be passed to the stored procedure, I just need to figure out why its not getting the datetime, everything else is so far fine. I just need to satisfy the parameter call for the @DateTime Parameter and it should probably update

Comment: string UpdateCommand = "sptimeupdate" + "'" + Clientid[up].ToString() + "'" + "'" +td.ToString()+ "'"; //This is the new one

Comment: You don't have any spaces in your command text and also no commas to seperate the different parameters.

Comment: Thanks, you was both right but I used the other guys method, it worked perfect because he had the commas in place and it I appreciate you both thanks