# how to update data from list view to database in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to update all rows from list view to database so, I define strings variable for string data and double variable for float data and then run a loop to fetch all data from list view to variable but failed to execute.

```
       int pro_sl_no=0;

       string pro_specification="";
       int Pro_qty = 0 ;
        string Pro_unit="";
        double pro_rate=0 ;
       double pro_amnt=0;
       double pro_gst=0;
        double pro_gst_amnt=0;
        double pro_net_amnt=0;


        for (int i = 0; i < listView_pro.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            pro_sl_no = Convert.ToInt32(listView_pro.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text);
            pro_specification = Convert.ToString(listView_pro.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
            Pro_qty = Convert.ToInt32(listView_pro.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
            Pro_unit = Convert.ToString(listView_pro.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
            pro_rate = Convert.ToDouble(listView_pro.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
            pro_amnt = Convert.ToDouble(listView_pro.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text);
            pro_gst = Convert.ToDouble(listView_pro.Items[i].SubItems[6].Text);
            pro_gst_amnt = Convert.ToDouble(listView_pro.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text);
            pro_net_amnt = Convert.ToDouble(listView_pro.Items[i].SubItems[8].Text);

            string sql="";
             sql += "update productADD set SL_NO=["pro_sl_no"],ro_specifi=["pro_specification"],pro_qty=["pro_qty"],pro_unit=["pro_unit"],pro_rate=["pro_rate"],pro_amo=["pro_amnt"],pro_gst=["pro_gst"],pro_gst_amo=["pro_gst_amnt"],total=["Pro_net_amnt"] where auto_no='"+txt_autoNo.Text.Trim()+"',addressee='"+txt_addressee.Text+"'";

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Comment: no its totally different     ..

Comment: no it's not. you are trying to do an update, and how to do it is described in the duplicate post. or why do you think it's totally different?

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have a sql statement embedded in code like this, you are exposing yourself to sql injection attacks, also you are opening a new database connection on every loop iteration.

Instead, you should use either an ORM, like EntityFramework, or have a separate DataLayer which interacts with Stored Procedures sitting in the database.

Also, there is no point in declaring the SQL variable like this: string sql=""; and then updating it in the following line.

For an example about how to implement an update using stredproc, please refer to this SO answer:
[Executing an update stored procedure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529293/executing-an-update-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp)

Comment: so sir can u please explain me a proper coding for this ?

Comment: while what you wrote is totally correct it shouldn't be posted as an answer to the question.

Comment: @Travelers, i updated my answer with a reference that should steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @gsharp, i think my answer is in line with the question, there would be no point to provide an answer to fix inline sql statements, if they are wrong and dangerous in principle.

Comment: sir i tried but not working ,basically i want to update list view data to data base ....so i want to fetch row wise all data from list view

Comment: First, create an object model containing all that variables and create a list of such objects. Second, keep adding to that list of objects inside listview loop. Third, outside the loop on the listview, have a method that accepts list of model objects in input. Forth, such method will have to traverse this list of objects and call the stored proc as detailed in the reference I added to my answer. You will have to add parameters to the storedproc based on the fields you want to update on the database.